# Calculate RMS, Count, SUM to array inside all columns of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, rms

I would like to calculate RMS, Count, SUM to array inside all columns of pandas dataframe and then fulfill outputs into new three dataframes as shown below

[image]

P.S > solution should deal with N numbers of columns, in my case, I have around 300 columns x,y,z,a,b,c ....... etc ...... N

ID           x                       y                   z  …..
EF407412    [471, 1084, 1360, 2284] [1408, 1572, 2277]  [977, 1003, 1493, 1519, 1650, 1676, 2804]   …..
KM043272    [2173]                  [1293, 2354,]       [1200]                                      …..
KM043273    …..                     …..                 …..                                         …..
….. ….. ….. ….. …..

Dataframe_RMS
ID          x           y           z   …..
EF407412    1454.5749   1792.4263   1685.6893   …..
KM043272    2173        1899.1004   1200        …..
KM043273    …..         …..         …..         …..
….. ….. ….. ….. …..

Dataframe_Count
ID          x           y           z   …..
EF407412    4           3           7   …..
KM043272    1           2           1   …..
KM043273    ….. …..         …..         …..
….. ….. ….. ….. …..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating answer as per the OP's comment - for any number of Columns Check Below code:

```
import pandas as pd 
from ast import literal_eval
import numpy as np 

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['EF407412','KM043272']
                   , 'x': ['[471, 1084, 1360, 2284]','[2173]']
                   , 'y': ['[1408, 1572, 2277]','[1293, 2354,]']
                   , 'z': ['[977, 1003, 1493, 1519, 1650, 1676, 2804]','[1200]']} )

col_num = df.shape[1]
```

## COUNT

```
df[[i+"_count" for i in df.columns[1:col_num]]] = df.apply(lambda x: ("{},"*(col_num-1))[:-1].\
                                                    format( *(tuple([len(literal_eval(x[col])) for col in df.columns[1:col_num]] ))),axis=1).\
                                                    astype('str').str.split(',', expand=True).values

df[['ID']+([ col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('count')])]
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

## SUM

```
df[[i+"_sum" for i in df.columns[1:col_num]]] = df.apply(lambda x: ("{},"*(col_num-1))[:-1].\
                                                    format( *(tuple([sum(literal_eval(x[col])) for col in df.columns[1:col_num]] ))),axis=1).\
                                                    astype('str').str.split(',', expand=True).values

df[['ID']+([ col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('sum')])]
```

Output:

[image]

## RMS

```
df[[i+"_rms" for i in df.columns[1:col_num]]] = df.apply(lambda x: ("{},"*(col_num-1))[:-1].\
                                                    format( *(tuple([np.sqrt(np.mean(np.square(literal_eval(x[col])))) for col in df.columns[1:col_num]] ))),axis=1).\
                                                    astype('str').str.split(',', expand=True).values

df[['ID']+([ col for col in df.columns if col.endswith('rms')])]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Abhishek for your kind support, I am looking for a solution that deals with N numbers of columns, in my case I have around 300 columns x,y,z,a,b,c ....... etc ...... N. as well as please share with me full implementation because I have received the error of name 'literal_eval' is not defined, Python version is 3.9.12, import ast is the correct library !!

Comment: from ast import literal_eval

Comment: faced this error : ValueError: malformed node or string: [1258, 1501, 1638, 1900, 2680, 2784, 3458, 3769, 3782, 3812, 3966, 4521, 4551, 4862, 5648, 6348, 6880, 7745, 8122, 8190, 8441, 9149, 9157, 9192, 9234]

Comment: Added & tried this value in example dataframe that mentioned in answer, working there, can you try